# How to take an integral when values aren't included or aren't part of my function?

Tags: calculus, probability, limits

My question is rather dumb, but it's making my head hurt. I have to calculate a continuous probability on some interval in the following way:

$p(0<x<0.5)=\int_0^.5 f(x) dx $

The problem I have is:

My function $f(x)$ is piecewise and takes a value of zero at x=0. And what I'm asked for doesn't include $0.5$ or $0$, so why is it appropriate to integrate this way (that is to say, why can I include these numbers as limits)? What's the criteria that determines how to take the integral when a point isn't included? My intuition is it has to do with limit rules, but I'd like to know the reason for it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is defined everywhere on the interval $a\lt x \lt b$, then:
$$\int_a^b f(x)\;dx =  \lim_{t\to a}\lim_{s\to b}\int_t^s f(x)\; dx$$
(if the limits exist)

Does that answer the question?

Comment: Well, it does. But taken into the context of this probability question, why is this appropriate? I mean, taking your example, 'a' and 'b' aren't part of the probability interval I care about, they're only close.